# How can I check string value in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, view

I have a model, and I want to show dome data, if `table_name == "something"`. All data are different, that is why I need to check. but when I write `==`, my View does not understand. It returns only `else` clause data. 
Please help me, how can I check the string value in view?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{                       
    if (item.table_name == "tPerson")
    { <a href="#" class="list-group-item">@item.user_group_name: <strong>@item.user_full_name</strong> | @item.date</a>;
    }
    else if (item.table_name == "tBook")
    { <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Book<strong>@item.book_name</strong> | @item.date</a>}
    else
    {<a href="#" class="list-group-item">@item.table_name  <strong>@item.name</strong> | @item.date</a>}

}
```

Comment: you should use strongly typed views.

Comment: What is the type of `table_name` and when it fails to match "tPerson" and "tBook" what exactly is its value?

Comment: Guys, everything is working when I add  item.table_name.TRIM ()

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "item.table_name" has the back Space or front space